Indexing overlapping areas of a numpy array
I have a 2D array of zeros (called labels) and a list of its coordinates (called centers). For each of the centers I would like to put a progressive number in a 5x5 cluster around it inside the label array.
Should two centers be so close that the corresponding clusters are overlapping, then I would like the labels arrays to give precedence to the lower label value. In other words, if cluster 2 is overlapping cluster 1, then I want cluster 1 to be 5x5 and cluster 2 to be smaller.
I have managed to code this procedure as follow:
import numpy as np

labels = np.zeros((10,20))
n_rows, n_cols = labels.shape

centers = [(4,4), (7,7), (5,10), (5,18)]


for i, center in enumerate(centers, start=1):
    # find the coordinates for the 5x5 cluster centered in center.
    cluster = np.ix_(np.arange(max(center[0]-2,0), min(center[0]+3,n_rows),1),
                     np.arange(max(center[1]-2, 0), min(center[1]+3,n_cols),1))
    
    # create a temporary label array with all zeros
    temp_label = np.zeros_like(labels)
    
    # set the label value in the temporary array in the position corresponding to the cluster 
    temp_label[cluster] = i
    
    # apply some boolean algebra
    # (labels == 0) is a bool array corresponding to all positions that are not yet belonging to a label
    # (labels == 0) * temp_label is like the temp_label, but only where the labels array is still free
    # adding the labels back is ensuring that all previous labels are also counted. 
    labels = (labels == 0) * temp_label + labels


print(labels)

Output:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

This snippet is actually doing what I want. Cluster 1 and 4 are full, while cluster 2 and 3 that are touching each other are only partial. To achieve this, I have to pass through a temporary array each time.
What would be a better solution?
Unfortunately reversing the center lists is not an option, because in the real analysis case, the center list is generated one element at the time.

About in the real analysis case, the center list is generated one element at the time. Either wait for it to be fully-constructed into a list like your centers; or else this entire question is invalid as it does not accurately demonstrate what you're actually doing.

The idea was to provide a small and running piece of code. There are several hundreds line of codes to make the real analysis case along with some real images being analyzed.

Surely you don't need "several hundred lines of code" to constrain the minimum reproducible example to one that requires iteration.

I am sorry, I am not as good as you in finding the best minimum reproducible example. Don't take it too personal, your answer is still great and will help somebody else in solving problems where they can wait for the full list of centers. That is not my case, but I have found anyway a better solution then mine.

It's OK. At this point, since you have answers, we wouldn't want to drastically modify your question or else it would constitute answer invalidation. If you want to post a new question demonstrating the iteration and update mechanism, you may be able to gather even better answers that help you.

Setup:
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

R, C = 10, 20
centers = [(4,4), (7,7), (5,10), (5,18)]
H, W = 5, 5

Solution:
buffer = np.zeros(((R + H), (C + W)))
labels = buffer[H//2:-H//2, W//2:-W//2]
view = swv(buffer, (H, W), writeable=True)

for lbl, (r, c) in enumerate(centers, start=1):
    patch = view[r, c]
    patch[patch == 0] = lbl

>>> print(labels)
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]


Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately reversing the order of center is not possible in the real analysis case.  I have edited the question.

@toto I have updated the solution

It almost works, the only issue I have now is with centers too close to the border. If you replace the last center with (5,18) it will fail creating the patch.

Aside from the reversal issues, you should avoid breaking vectorisation by using a for loop.

@toto updated the solution again!

@Reinderien I think OP is looking for a for loop solution. After all, if collecting the centers to a list was feasible, then reversing would be too.

The for loop in the example doesn't exists in the real case. What I was actually looking was the trickery of the sliding window.
In my original plan was to select indeces to be labeled using the boolean condition (label == 0) and the list of indeces generated by the ix_.

You can write the patch in a reverse order so to avoid a complicated (more expensive) mask-based computation.
Writing very small patches will always be expensive with Numpy, though there are certainly faster pure-Numpy solutions (also probably convoluted ones). This is because Numpy is optimized for computing large arrays, and any vectorized operation will be clearly sub-optimal due to expensive relatively-large temporary arrays (making the code even more memory-bound). The key to this problem is simply to use compilation-based modules like Numba or Cython.

Out-of-order solution
Here is a solution in Numba mixing both solutions:
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def compute_naive(centers):
    labels = np.zeros((10,20))

    for i, center in enumerate(centers, start=1):
        cluster = np.ix_(np.arange(center[0]-2, center[0]+3,1), 
                         np.arange(center[1]-2, center[1]+3,1))
        temp_label = np.zeros_like(labels)
        temp_label[cluster] = i
        labels = (labels == 0) * temp_label + labels

    return labels

@nb.njit('(int32[:,::1],)')
def compute_numba(centers):
    labels = np.zeros((10,20))

    for i, center in enumerate(centers[::-1]):
        cy, cx = center
        yStart, yEnd = max(cy-2, 0), min(cy+3, labels.shape[0])
        xStart, xEnd = max(cx-2, 0), min(cx+3, labels.shape[1])
        for y in range(yStart, yEnd):
            for x in range(xStart, xEnd):
                labels[y, x] = centers.shape[0] - i

    return labels

centers = [(4,4), (7,7), (5,10), (5,17)]
npCenters = np.array(centers, dtype=np.int32)
assert np.allclose(compute_naive(centers), compute_numba(npCenters))
%timeit -n 1000 labels = compute_numba(npCenters)


In-order solution (update)
If you cannot reverse the order and each patch is computed one by one, then I doubt there is a much faster Numpy solution. That being said, Numba can still help to improve performance though applying patchs one by one in-order will be a bit slower. Here is a Numba solution:
@nb.njit('(int32[:,::1],)')
def compute_numba_inorder(centers):
    labels = np.zeros((10,20), dtype=np.int32)
    mask = np.zeros_like(labels, dtype=np.int8)

    for i, center in enumerate(centers):
        cy, cx = center
        yStart, yEnd = max(cy-2, 0), min(cy+3, labels.shape[0])
        xStart, xEnd = max(cx-2, 0), min(cx+3, labels.shape[1])
        for y in range(yStart, yEnd):
            for x in range(xStart, xEnd):
                if mask[y, x] == 0:
                    labels[y, x] = i + 1
                    mask[y, x] = 1

    return labels


Benchmark
Initial code (in-order):          97.2 µs

Chrysophylaxs (out-of-order):     29.6 µs
This Numba code (out-of-order):    1.0 µs

Chrysophylaxs (in-order):         48.4 µs
This Numba code (in-order):        1.2 µs    <-----

The (in-order) Numba solution is about 80 times faster than the initial code on this very-small example. It should be even faster on larger-scale use-cases. Note the overhead of a Numpy function call is generally about 1 µs on my machine so no Numpy code can be faster than that.

Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately reversing the order of center is not possible in the real analysis case.  I have edited the question.  I will try to see what advantage numba can bring.

This is a very important detail to provide. I updated the answer accordingly. Note the generation of the patches should likely take more time than setting patches to the final array (at least with a compiled fast Numba/Cython code). Also please note that Cython might be better suited for iterative generation of patches, especially if patches are generated using an external library.

Numba is not a magic wand. We should prefer a solution that uses vectorisation first.

I'm not very proficient in numba, but I will have a look at how to implement it in the real case.

Using 0 for empty cells is going to be a problem. Use NaN instead:
import numpy as np

centers = np.array(((4, 4), (7, 7), (5, 10), (5, 17)))
label_idx = np.arange(len(centers))
offsets = np.arange(-2, 3)

# * 2 (dimensions) * 5 (offsets) * 4 (centers)
i, j = centers.T[:, np.newaxis, :] + offsets[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
# 5 (offsets) * 5 (offsets) * 4 (centers), reshaped to 25x4
i = np.broadcast_to(i[:, np.newaxis, :], (offsets.size, offsets.size, label_idx.size)).reshape((-1, label_idx.size))
j = np.broadcast_to(j[np.newaxis, :, :], (offsets.size, offsets.size, label_idx.size)).reshape((-1, label_idx.size))

labels = np.full(shape=(10, 21, label_idx.size), fill_value=np.nan)
labels[i, j, label_idx] = 1 + label_idx[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
labels = np.nanmin(labels, axis=-1)
print(labels)


The OP stated that "the center list is generated one element at the time" so I wonder if this vectorized solution would fit to the OP.

Unclear. If the centre list is not available all at once, then either (a) wait for it to be, and/or (b) the entire question is invalid as it's non-representative.

I guess the OP uses an inherently iterative solution reading the resulting (iterative) labels. Otherwise, reversing the list would not have been an issue in the first place (though the memory use also matter). I agree that the question is probably non-representative...
